# Tribonacci Numbers and Time/Space Complexity - C

Tags: c, recursion

Hey guys I wrote a program that takes an input and calculates the [Tribonacci](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html) number:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: Hanna
 *
 * Created on October 13, 2018, 10:25 PM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


unsigned long Tribonacci(int n)
{  if (n < 3)
       return 1;
    if (n >= 3)
        return Tribonacci(n - 1) + Tribonacci(n - 2) + Tribonacci(n - 3);
}

int main () {
   char number[100];
   char *ptr;
   long num;

    while (1){
        printf("Please enter the integer number n>3: ");
        fgets(number, 10, stdin);
        num = strtol(number, &ptr, 10);
        printf("Tribonacci number is %ld\n", Tribonacci(num));
    }

   return(0);
}
```

For some reason it gives the wrong answer. Example:

```
N=24 should give 755476, instead it gives 978793
```

I don't know why. The Tribonnaci() function seems to be okay. Also, is this optimizing space and time complexity?

Note: I'm required to use recursion.

Comment: Please add a reason for the downvote..

Comment: I'm not the DVer, but "gives the wrong answer" is [too] vague. What would be better is (e.g.): _Given an input value of 12, the answer I get is 17, but it should be 19_. So, edit your question accordingly. Also, have you tried single stepping with a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) or adding temporary/debug `printf` statements?

Comment: Yes, for example N=24 should give 755476, instead it gives 978793

Comment: The first Tribonacci numbers T_n starting with n=0 are  0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7,... If you were not pressed to use the recursion: the nth-powers of the matrix [0,0,1;1,1,1;0,1,0]  have the Tribonacci-numbers in (1,2) and (3,1). That would be faster and uses less space

Comment: There seem to be mildly divergent definitions for the first terms of the tribonacci sequence, but once you get going with 2, 4, 7, … they are the same.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers) vs [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to make a few points.

1. It only makes sense to calculate tribonacci of n <= 73, because a number larger than that does not fit into an unsigned long.
2. I am assuming that you are allowed to use memoization. It is basically a technique that consists of storing the answer to the problem the first time you compute it, so when you need it later you will not have to calculate it again.

I will now justify why you should use memoization to this problem. Imagine that you want to compute Tribonacci(5). Your program will have to do the following function calls.

[image]

So you will end up calling Tribonacci(3) two times, and doing some work twice. If you simulate this recursion tree for N larger than 5, you will visualize that you are doing a lot of duplicate work on the recursion tree.

I made a version for your code that applies memoization. The idea is that for every Tribonacci(x), we will compute it only once and then store it's value for when it is called again later.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long memorize[75];

unsigned long Tribonacci(int n)
{
    if(memorize[n] > 0) return memorize[n];
    else if(n == 0) return memorize[n] = 0;
    else if(n < 3) return memorize[n] = 1;
    else return memorize[n] = (Tribonacci(n - 1) + Tribonacci(n - 2) + Tribonacci(n - 3) );
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Insert the Tribonacci you want to calculate");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%lld\n", Tribonacci(n) );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I have adapted the code to handle this case!

Answer (score 1):

Coding error: `Tribonacci(0)` is 0.

```
// if (n < 3) return 1;
if (n < 3)
   return (n > 0);
```

[... for n = 0, 1, 2, ... are 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, ...](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html)

---

> Also, is this optimizing space and time complexity?

No.  Better to not recalculate.

Below is  a version that calculates `Tribonacc(n)` in linear time.  Recursion is used.

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned long tn, tnm1, tnm2;
} Tribonacci_T;

static Tribonacci_T Tribonacci_helper(int n) {
  if (n < 3) {
    return (Tribonacci_T) {.tn = n > 0, .tnm1 = n > 1, .tnm2 = n > 2};
  }
  Tribonacci_T t = Tribonacci_helper(n - 1);
  return (Tribonacci_T) {.tn = t.tn + t.tnm1 + t.tnm2, .tnm1 = t.tn, .tnm2 = t.tnm1};
}

unsigned long Tribonacci(int n) {
  return Tribonacci_helper(n).tn;
}
```